# Как убрать мигание скрытых блоков AngularJS в момент загрузки страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Как сделать изначально скрытыми блоки, которые должны показываться только при выполнении условия в `ng-show`?

```
<span class="help-inline" ng-show="arr.length == 0">Пустой массив!</span>
```

В момент загрузки страницы, пока выполняются различные действия в контроллере, эта надпись на мгновение появляется, и затем скрывается. 
В контроллере:

```
$scope.arr = [];
...
```

затем происходит запрос к серверу через `$http` и получение элементов для массива arr, и он либо заполняется, либо остается пустым.

Таких запросов для разных переменных может быть и несколько, соответственно, если я правильно понимаю, чем больше запросов, тем дольше показ блоков, которые должны быть скрытыми - пока не выполнятся все действия в контроллере.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хватает просто убрать декларацию `$scope.arr = [];`

Массив нужно декларировать когда вы получаете элементы из сервера, т.е. после запроса к серверу:

```
MyService.getSomething().then(function (something) {
    $scope.arr = something;
});
```

Именно для таких случаев angular не вылетает ошибки когда в темплетах пишем `{{arr.length}}` и `arr` ещё `undefined`.

Сравниваете **[этот fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/w4ty5xg1/1/)** с **[этим](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/w4ty5xg1/2/)**. В последним, я лишь прокомментировал декларацию массива до запроса.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте лоадер во время выполнения операции. Например, из [этой статьи](http://habrahabr.ru/post/197762/).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать [ngCloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

Comment: Директива `ngCloak` помогла бы скрывать блок пока он ещё не скомпилирован. В этом случае не помогает: автору мешает тот факт, что массив пустой пока данные ещё не получены от сервера.